# Tomcat/Java OCSP revocation check

Tags: java, tomcat, ocsp

I have a question about OCSP check and certificates. I have a Tomcat/Java set-up where a HTTPS connector is configured to always require a client certificate - 2 way TLS.

In this scenario I can enable revocation check on client certificates connecting on my connector by setting

```
SSLHostConfig.setCertificateVerification("REQUIRED");
SSLHostConfig.setRevocationEnabled(true);
```

The problem is now revocation check is enabled for ALL Certificates, even for such that do not have OCSP information in them. I wish to not check for revocation if no OCSP information is provided (some certificates do not provide it). A CRL failover should be disabled or always return okay.

Has anyone done anything similar or has some tips? Thanks.